# project euler #59,Wrong Answer

Tags: python-3.x

I don't know that why this code doesn't give the correct answer

I ran this code on intel core i3 processor

```
from array import array

with open("cipher.txt","r") as file:

    main_list=file.read().split(",")

sub_list1=array("i",[])

sub_list2=array("i",[])

sub_list3=array("i",[])

for i in range(len(main_list)):

    if i%3==0:

        sub_list1.append(int(main_list[i]))

    elif i%3==1:

        sub_list2.append(int(main_list[i]))

    else:

        sub_list3.append(int(main_list[i]))


def is_valid(xor):

     if 32 <= xor <= 90:

        return True

     elif 97 <= xor <= 122:

        return True

     return False


ASCIIs2=list(range(97,123))

_lists=[sub_list1,sub_list2,sub_list3]

codes=[]

while len(codes)!=len(main_list):

    for _list in _lists:

        for key in ASCIIs2:

            codes_copy=[]

            for value in _list:

                n=int(value)^key

                if is_valid(n) :

                    codes_copy.append(int(value)^key)

                else:

                    break

            else:

                codes+=codes_copy

                break


print(sum(codes))
```

According to the answer,sub_list1 should be decrypted by 103 but this says it decrypted by 101

Comment: not everyone knows what project you're talking about, can you edit your question to show what you're trying to achieve? can you show what is in that file (`chiper.txt`)?

Comment: https://projecteuler.net/problem=59    (you can see the question from the following link)

Answer (score 0):

I am suffering from the same problem and found out that the cipher file has been changed and all the answers available on the internet are specifically for that older version of the file. Because it contained some Bible text which made some people quite upset. You can read further here: [project euler-problem059](https://projecteuler.chat/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=6942&hilit=59&start=80).

Comment: Hey, Aditya. We actually encourage typing up the answers in StackOverflow, not just linking to other resources. Just imagine what will happen if that post is deleted, then your answer will become useless. Can you please type up the answer from the form here?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of brute forcing it, you can apply frequency analysis quite easily.
You know that the key consists of three lower case characters with the first char coding for text[0,3,...], the second letter codes for [1,4,...] and the third one for [2,5,...].
Split your text in 3 parts, find the most common number used in each part and the key will be the xor result of the most common number ^ the most used character in English.

apply the key to the text, convert the clear text to ascii numbers, sum it and try the challenge 60 :)

SPOILER ALERT:

- the most common character is ' ' (space).
- the key is related to Euler...

code below:

```
def decrypt(array,key):
    en = []
    j = 0
    for i in range(len(array)):
        en.append(chr(array[i]^int(ord(key[j]))))
        j+=1
        if j>2:
            j = 0
    en = ''.join(en)
    
    return en

def to_ascii(text):
    return [ord(c) for c in text]

def main():
    #read the crypted text
    f = open('cipher.txt')
    cipher = f.read().strip().split(',')
    f.close()

    #convert to int
    cipher = [int(x) for x in cipher]

    #cut in 3 parts
    c = []
    for i in range(3):
        c.append(cipher[i::3])

    #find the most used char in each / it should be ' '
    key = []

    for i in range(3):
        dic = {}
        for ch in c[i]:
            if ch in dic:
                dic[ch] +=1
            else:
                dic[ch] = 1

        #reverse the dic
        dic = {dic[k]:k for k in dic}
        crypted = max(dic.items())[1]
    
        #reverse the xor to get the key that makes the number = ' '
        key.append(chr(crypted^ord(' ')))

    key = ''.join(key)

    #decrypt / convert and sum
    return sum(to_ascii(decrypt(cipher,key)))
```